# Why is accessing an array's element by its index slower than using the .find() function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For the particular case below, it seems using the .find function is significantly faster than simply using the element's index. Why is this?

[image: jsPerf Results]

Comment: Please put the actual code, not just a screenshot

Comment: beacuse .find() performs a search and index is a straight address of the value in the array?!

Comment: This test seems flawed. Finding any of those values anyway you care to mention (there's only 4 of them) is going to practically instantaneous.My guess is the times are so tiny that whatever performance tool your using can't measure them accurately.

Comment: @blewherself So you are saying search is supposed to be slower? Seems to me like you misread the question.

Comment: You should set up a test case using far more elements.

Comment: @Jonah yup. my bad

Comment: @Liam you were right but it wasn't the whole story. On a 100K element array they performed almost identically, leading me to believe .find does some sort of caching, because in Nina's answer with random numbers, indexing is much faster.

Comment: Indexing will be faster.A find has to iterate all the elements until it finds what it wants. An index goes directly to the address in memory and will always be faster. That said you can iterate a lot of elements in not very much time at all so your talking very small numbers here. Remember [*Premature optimisation is the root of all evil*](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a different approach by using a random number to find the object.

Index:

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    o = array[i];
```

vs Find:

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    o = array.find(o => o.id === i);
```

with shared data

```
var array = [{ id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 8 }, { id: 9 }];
```

Then you get from [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/index-vs-array-find) (with EDGE):

```
Index: 31,707,818 ±0.    92% fastest
Find:   5,001,388 ±1.51% 84% slower
```

**Conclusion**

Index access is faster then using [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: The randomness must be what did it, because I did another .find test case with a 100K element array and the two tests were extremely close (78 ops per sec vs 82 ops per sec). Perhaps .find is doing some sort of caching?

Answer (score 1):

Both samples took less than 0ms

```js
var now = new Date();
var items = [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
var item = items[2];
document.write((new Date().getTime() - now.getTime()) + 'ms');
```

```js
var now = new Date();
var items = [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
var item = items.find(e => e.id === 2);
document.write((new Date().getTime() - now.getTime()) + 'ms');
```

But with 100K array size the picture is different

```js
var items = [];

for(var id = 0; id < 100000; id++) {
  items.push({id: id});
}

var now = new Date();
var item = items[99999];
document.write((new Date().getTime() - now.getTime()) + 'ms');
```

```js
var items = [];

for(var id = 0; id < 100000; id++) {
  items.push({id: id});
}

var now = new Date();
var item = items.find(e => e.id === 99999);
document.write((new Date().getTime() - now.getTime()) + 'ms');
```

As you can see of course direct access by index is much faster because the `find` method should check many items before it finds the correct one. I.e. the topic starter assumption (that direct access by index is slower than `find` method) is obviously incorrect

Comment: Even with 10k elements still 0ms for me

Comment: @cyrix It is 0ms and 1ms.

Comment: It's also going to alter depending on what element your searching for `find`s complexity is `O(1)` at it's most efficient and `O(n)` at it's least. `items[999]` will be `O(1)` always

Comment: @liam that's true